# SDWebImage library load only two image

Tags: ios, image, caching, imageview, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage library for caching image for UICollectionView that is download from url,every time it send all request but download only two image. Can anyone know the reason??? Thanks in advance.

The code is:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[fileimagepath objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                 options:0
                progress:nil
               completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
 {

     if (image == nil)
     {

         NSLog(@"image Not received");
     }
     else
     {
         cell.imageview.image = image;


     }
 }];
```

Comment: please put your code here.

Comment: How should we know without the code? Please post it as an edit to your post.

Comment: which method are you using to set image? I created category for ActivityIndicator and to show basic animation while displaying image to image view: https://github.com/ersanjana/SDImageCache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method name is change

used this method

```
- (id<SDWebImageOperation>)
    downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
                 options:(SDWebImageOptions)options
                progress:
                    (__strong SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock
               completed:(__strong SDWebImageCompletionWithFinishedBlock)
    completedBlock;
```

Comment: Thank you, please see my code again, my *manager object calling your given method. isn't it???

Comment: you use `downloadWithURL` and i told `downloadImageWithURL `.

Comment: Thanks Sumit Grag, but when i use downloadImageWithURL an error show that "No visible @inteface for downloadImageWithURL"

Comment: Now download latest version of SDWebImage , Good Luck.

Comment: yap using SDWebImage 3.7.1(updated) now it works , Thank You Very much.